# What is the head of the noun phrase "none of the members"?

Tags: noun-phrases

What is the head of the noun phrase "none of the members"?

I'm not sure if none or members is the head of the noun phrase.

Comment: Well, it isn't of the members, is it?

Answer (score 1):

"None" is the pronoun that is the head of the noun phrase.  The other noun, "members" is the object of the preposition "of".

"of the members" is modifying the "none".